# Difference between super keyword and inheritance class in java

Tags: java

I'm just confusing with super keyword and inheritance in java.

Super keyword is used to call all the properties of main class whereas inheritance concept also used to call all the properties of main class. So Why we have to use super keyword? What is the main difference between Super keyword and Inheritance ?

I'm just confusing with this one.Can anyone help me for this clarification please?

Comment: One is a keyword and one is a concept

Answer (score 1):

> Super keyword is used to call all the properties of main class

No, it isn't. It's a keyword used to call members of a parent class.

> whereas inheritance concept also used to call all the properties of main class

Inheritance itself calls nothing. Inheritance is the name of the concept that allows you to re-use members of a parent class in a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly refer to methods and fields in the parent class of the current class using the `super` keyword. This is useful in constructors, when methods are overridden in te subclass and you want to call the otherwise inaccessible method from the superclass, or to access fields that are shadowed by the subclass.

However when you haven't overridden a method or shadowed a field in a subclass, you can access it without using the `super` keyword, by just referring to its name, because your subclass *inherited* these methods and fields.

There is a slight difference between that and using super - if you later override or shadow that method or field, the super keyword still refers to the superclass while referring by name only will then point to the implementation in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply**

The super keyword in java is a reference variable that is used to refer parent class objects.  The keyword `super` came into the picture with the concept of Inheritance.

**SUPER()  Is**

1. To access the data members of parent class when both parent and child class have member with same name
2. To explicitly call the no-arg and parameterized constructor of parent class
3. To access the method of parent class when child class has overridden that method.